# What do these runes in Adventure Time say?

Tags: languages, adventure-time

Adventure Time has its own [runic alphabet](http://adventuretime.wikia.com/wiki/Runic_code) which seems to be a combination of [Elder Futhark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elder_Futhark), [Younger Futhark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Younger_Futhark), [Anglo-Saxon runes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anglo-Saxon_futhorc), [Futhork](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Medieval_runes) and [Cirth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cirth).

In episode 6x15, this appears in the background at about 54seconds:

[image: calendar runes]

Most other examples of the runes have a clear transcription, but I can't work this out at all. It appears to be on a calendar, and the first rune is almost certainly "A", and the only month that begins with A and has 5 letters is April, but none of the other runes (in any of the aforementioned systems) align with those letters. To make things worse, the calendar shows exactly 28 days, and the only month with exactly 28 days is February.

Is there any way to work out what these runes say?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[From the wikia:](http://adventuretime.wikia.com/wiki/Runic_code)

[image]

So the chart spells out:

A--D-

If you accept that the second letter is D. It is not a perfect match, though.

I don't think it has to be a calendar, it could however be a chart. Or a game. Also, the squares are crossed out sporadically, who does that with a calendar(at least your not suppose to). It could also be a map of landmarks or where something is buried.

Alternately this could be impossible to solve if all of the letters in the alphabet aren't released. It would be like a impossible game of hangman.

To supply the rest of the letters, I used a alternate rune calendar and got a bunch of random letters. But this is described through:

[From the wikia:](http://adventuretime.wikia.com/wiki/Runic_code)

> It is interesting to note that, **while the alphabet used in the series**
>   **is, indeed, runic, some characters are used improperly**

So unless you have a complete alphabet, this might be impossible to solve just yet.

The last letter is supposed to be Z in many other tables, but that is not a rule. And the backward F can mean many things.

If you compare [to this chart](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runes), the rune word's meaning appears to be gibberish.

I even looked through locations and characters it could be referencing to and I couldn't find a match. So I would say that the answer has not been revealed yet.

And it doesn't seem to have anything to do with [runic calendars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runic_calendar), either.

Rather disappointingly, it could just be something that was stuck on the background as cameo.

And it doesn't seem to follow any other rune alphabet and that could mean that the alphabet terms missing could be anything.

You could try asking a person that knows runes, but the show doesn't follow a set alphabet.

### Another assumption I had

I had this assumption while writing this post earlier, but decided not to add it do to the following errors. But after a comment mentioned it again, I decided to add this an answer.

The calendar could be spelling out **August**. I came to this assumption due to the that "calendar" looks like a calendar and the episode was indeed aired August,7. But the word would be missing a "G".

The first letter is obviously A.

The next letter is unknown.

The next letter could be seen as "U". It does not look exactly like it, so that is why I decided not to assume.

The 4th letter could be seen as "st", but not using the adventure time rune translation, Instead you have to use a alternate chart.

And the last letter using that chart would indeed be x or z.

Anyway you cut it, it wouldn't spell either April or August.

So the word would Spell.

A-USTDX

A-USTDZ

A-U-DZ

A-U-DX

I personally think it probably means nothing. We are looking to much into it.

Comment: Does this help fill in the gaps? http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=A__D_&x=0&y=0

Comment: @Pureferret Fascinating, but the show doesn't follow a set alphabet. Also, I'm not sure the 4th letter is even D. And the last letter is either x or z, probably.

Comment: I do know runes, including ones invented by Tolkien (the second rune is a certh). I've written down so many combinations of what these runes could be and none make sense :[

Comment: If you look at the futorch (Anglosaxon) runes, the 4th rune translates as "st". the "h" looking one *could* be cen or c. Using that chart it would by ae - ? - cen/c - st - x. Considering that the air date was early August, I'm guessing it could be an attempt at spelling August.

Comment: @JohnP I thought that, but I didn't add it it because it doesn't look like exactly like it. I'll edit it to add all of my assumptions. But it can't be trying to be spell august.

Comment: I think I have to deal with the fact that it is just nonsense :[

Comment: Also, I thought the third rune looked a bit like a poorly written sigel (S), or maybe cen as said above. But that still doesn't help at all.

Comment: @Cameron Ball I thought it might be a date and time. because DX means 510 in roman numerals or it might be coordinates.